Where can I find documentation for the IBM.WMQ.PCF library in .NET Framework?
I’m currently working with the IBM.WMQ.PCF (Programmable Command Format) library in .NET version 4.6.1. I’ve been unable to find any specific .NET class documentation related to this library on the IBM website. Can anyone provide references or point me to official documentation or resources for this library? Specifically, I’m looking for details on its supported versions and any deprecation notices.
Thanks in advance!
Update:
I am exploring PCF classes to develop a monitoring solution for IBM MQ. Specifically, I’m focusing on monitoring queue managers, queues, listeners, and channels available in different MQ Servers that can communicate with each other. So I rely on PCF classes to get the Queues, Channels & Listeners names and basic details (if possible) from specified Queue Manager.

The .Net PCF classes are not, and have never been, a formally supported public interface. So there's no specific documentation. Instead, the recommendation is to consider using the REST admin interface.

Thanks for the Reply! However, I am exploring this option to develop a monitoring system for IBM MQ that involves multiple MQ servers. As per this document (https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/ibm-mq/9.2?topic=administering-administration-using-rest-api), I need to run the API in any one mq web server and need a dedicated Queue manager as Gateway, right? Since I cannot ask every user to do so I think this will not help for my case. Please correct me If I am wrong.
